# AngularFire custom order by ranking

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm trying to sort teams by ranking, using AngularFire and Firebase.

In Firebase I have 4 teams where I store only the name.
I also store matches, which have a reference to both teams disputing that match and the score for each one.

The matches node looks like this:

```
matches    
    -KQgphN_5692GySN0Oxz
        home_team: teamA
        away_team: teamB
        score
            home: 1
            away: 2
    -KQlu6XLak6LgAr9cTty
        home_team: teamC
        away_team: teamD
        score
            home: 2
            away: 2
```

And the teams node:

```
teams
    teamA
        name: "Team A"
    teamB
        name: "Team B"
    teamC
        name: "Team C"
    teamD
        name: "Team D"
```

So, I need to order these teams by vitories, draws and losses by watching the results in realtime.

I have a ng-repeat that lists teams like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="team in teams">{{team.name}}</li>
```

So, how can I order these teams by wins, taking in account that a win is equivalent to 3 points, a draw is 1 point and a loss is 0 points?

With the above matches example, the ranking should be:

1 - Team B

2 - Team C

3 - Team D

4 - Team A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order a Firebase Database query by a nested value, as long as that nested value is at a fixed path. This means you'll need to store the score for each team, e.g.

```
teams
    teamA
        name: "Team A"
        score: 20
    teamB
        name: "Team B"
        score: 12
    teamC
        name: "Team C"
        score: 42
    teamD
        name: "Team D"
        score: 31
```

With this structure, you can load the top teams in order with:

```
var leaders = ref.child('teams').orderByChild('score').limitToLast(3);
leaders.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    leaders.forEach(function(leaderSnapshot) {
        console.log(leaderSnapshot.child('name').val());
    });
});
```

This will print:

> Team A
>
> Team D
>
> Team C

So to get the leaderboard, you'll need to invert them.